# How to access viewpager from a view from the pageradapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have a ViewPager and a custom PagerAdapter.
In the pager adapter there is a view that `onClick` I would like to move to the next page.
I implemented the following:

```
@Override  
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {     
  view.setOnClickListener(
     (view) -> {  
        int current = ((ViewPager)container).getCurrentItem(); 
        ((ViewPager) container).setCurrentItem(current + 1, true);  
    }   
  );    
}
```

This works but I am not sure I should be accessing the view pager from inside the adapter like that.
What is the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is ok. If you want cleaner arcitecture you should pass `ViewPager` as an interface to your adapter. And your code will be like this:

```
public interface Pager {
    /**
    * Super method where you do 
    * int current = ((ViewPager)container).getCurrentItem(); 
    * ((ViewPager) container).setCurrentItem(current + 1, true);  
    * but in ViewPager. So you don't need to cast it any more.
    */
    void goToNextItem();
}

private Pager pager;

@Override  
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {     
  view.setOnClickListener(
     (view) -> {  
        pager.goToNextItem();
    }   
  );    
}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to have a reference to the viewpager from the adapter when there is also the reference from the viewpager to the adapter? I.e. circular dependency

Comment: It's ok. GC can easily handle it, so there is nothing to worry about

Answer (score 0):

@Anton Potapov's method works well, but an easier way would be to make your viewpager public  and access it using its parent like below:

```
((ParentActivity)context).viewPager.setCurrentItem(position++);
```